# How do I bind a StackPanel to my ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In my view I have this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

which binds to my ViewModel's Title property and **this is straightforward and works well**:

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return _title;
    }

    set
    {
        _title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Title");
    }
}
```

**However my ViewModel also has the Property "FormFields"** which is a StackPanel that contains a number of other UserControls:

```
private StackPanel _formFields;
public StackPanel FormFields
{
    get
    {
        return _formFields;
    }

    set
    {
        _formFields = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FormFields");
    }
}
```

**How do I bind this from my view?**

In ASP.NET there was a **PlaceHolder** element, I'm looking for something with the same functionality, e.g.

**PSEUDO CODE:**

```
<PlaceHolder Content="{Binding FormFields}"/>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, don't. Instead of dictating the UI from your VM, you should be dictating data (the model). In other words, the property type should be `ObservableCollection<FormField>`. Then your view would bind as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FormFields}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is generally defined in the `.Resources` section of a parent element. I.e `Window.Resources` or `WrapPanel.Resources`.

Having said that, you can use a `ContentPresenter` to grab the `StackPanel` and stick it in the visual tree:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding FormFields}"/>
```

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I couldn't get it to work with ItemsSource and hence discovered that you can just make a ViewModel Property to be a XAML Element which seemed to be a very useful pattern, will have to rethink this, but the ContentPresenter works well for now, thanks.

Comment: There is no ItemsSource property for StackPanel.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx << msdn says the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` is of type `ItemsPanelTemplate`, so don't you need to wrap the `<StackPanel/>` so that it's `<ItemsPanelTemplate><StackPanel/></ItemsPanelTemplate>` ?

Comment: Seven years old this may be, but your ContentPresenter remark has made my day, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `Border` or just a plain `Grid`?

```
<Border Content="{Binding FormFields}" />
```

Still, I'm questioning the design. The Form Fields should live in a view, and the view should be specified in data template which is instantiated based on the view model type. I wouldn't personally do what you're doing in code.

Cheers.