# Binding Stackpanel in DataTemplate

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I have the following DataTemplate for a listbox:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MoviesTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding S_Poster}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Theaters_S}" FontSize="16"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel ItemsSource="To be bound to the custom stack"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I need to bind the stack **"StackPanel ItemsSource="To be bound to the custom stack"** to a stackpanel i define in C# code named **"Stack_PIC"** referring to a stack of pics which is coded as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i < full; i++)
{
   Image star = new Image();
   star.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Small_F.png", UriKind.Relative));
   d.Rating_PIC.Children.Add(star);
}
```

My purpose behind this is to add **rating stars** to the **ListBoxItems**, So what is the correct way to bind the content of this stack to the following custom content??

**UPDATE:**

I kow that the stackpanel can't be bind this way and the alternative is to use a structure called ItemsControl as shown in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964170/how-do-i-bind-a-stackpanel-to-my-viewmodel). However, i didn't understand the complete answer there and how to map it to my case so any help to clarify this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define an ItemsSource on a StackPanel. So you should try to solve your problem using a ListBox or some other ItemsControl object.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525464/wpf-databinding-stackpanel) should get you on the way.

Also, perhaps consider using a premade starrating control (which I think you are trying to do, right?) , take a look at [this](http://nickeandersson.blogs.com/blog/2008/02/a-rating-contro.html) one.