# Create new ViewB + ViewmodelB in other ViewModelA and show them in ViewA

Tags: c#, wpf

I use MVVM. I have a ViewA with a Grid in xaml and a ViewModelA. In the ViewModelA I have a Method that looks like this which is called on a Button click:

```
public void ButtonClickMethod()
{
    ViewB viewB = new ViewB();
    viewB.DataContext = new ViewBViewModel();
}
```

How do I add all the created viewBs into the Grid on my ViewA, so I can see them there? Or is my solution wrong in general maybe?

**EDIT :**

I now used a `ObservableCollection<ViewB>` in my ViewModelA which notifies on changes in my ViewA xaml at

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollection<ViewB>}" />
```

The only problem is the ViewBs shown in the ItemControl should be dragable. Therefore I used expression blend's

`Interaction.GetBehaviors(ViewB).Add(new MouseDragElementBehavior() { });`

when i create a new ViewB. But it doesn't work.

**EDIT2 :**

I tried this solution but it doesn't work for me :( [Using MouseDragElementBehavior with an ItemsControl and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358774/using-mousedragelementbehavior-with-an-itemscontrol-and-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

Add your Grid an ContentControl and bind it content to your second view.

Here an example with an UserControl.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Content="{Binding SecondView}"/>
```

Code im ViewModel:

```
private UserControl secondView;
public UserControl SecondView
{
  get
  {
    return secondView;
  }
  set
  {
    this.SetProperty(ref secondView,value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Every time I push the button a new secondView is generated and should be added to the grid on the firstView. Don't I have to use something like a collection? The contentControl now binds to 1 specific secondView, but I can create multiple of them dynamically.

Comment: ok...
Maybe this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964170/how-do-i-bind-a-stackpanel-to-my-viewmodel) will help you.